# OS X Lion: App-Specific Resume

Tags: macos, resume

I know there's a system wide preference to disable 'Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps', but is there any way to have it restore only specific apps?. I would like to have Safari open in full screen every time I launch it.

Answer (score 2):

`defaults write com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool YES` will enable it just for Safari.

Note that you can also temporarily toggle the behavior by holding ⌥ and choosing **Safari** → **Quit And Keep Windows** (or ⌘-⌥-Q).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to DISABLE restore for a particular application, it appears you can close all open documents for a program, quit the program, then go to ~/Library/Saved Application State/«app name», Get Info, and lock the folder.

This could work to preserve the state of "no windows open", or to preserve any other window state that you always want to launch into.