# Making it so programs aren't restored after startup from a forced shutdown

Tags: macos

Whenever I boot up from a forced shutdown (aka holding down the power button), OSX restores all the programs I had open before the forced shutdown. Is there a way to disable this? If my computer turns off for whatever reason, I want it to boot up fresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log out once and uncheck the **Reopen windows when logging back in** toggle.

It should stick and cover you next time you have to crash land your mac. 
Do be sure to check this setting in the General preference.

[image]

Lastly, some more tacky per-app solutions are running around like locking the folders where state is saved. [OS X Lion: App-Specific Resume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20507/os-x-lion-app-specific-resume)

Comment: NO, that is NOT a solution! That only regulates regular restart. Kernel panic does not honor that checkbox.

Comment: If by "more tacky" you mean "more robust in the face of crashes" then yes, [that](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20508/9388) works :-)

Comment: @mee I would say a kernel panic is different than a forced shutdown, but perhaps that's my training and the OP is really looking for a solution when the OS misbehaves so badly that the OS pulls the plug and doesn't even shut down. You could ask a similar question if you are looking for a derivative of what the asker here has accepted as an answer to their problem.